# AIORedis and PUB/SUB aren't asnyc

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I used [aioredis](http://aioredis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html) for writing async service which will listen on a certain channel and run some commands in async manner.

Basically I took a code from [examples page](http://aioredis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html) to write a small test-app and removed unnecessary parts:

```
import asyncio
import aioredis

async def reader(ch):
    while (await ch.wait_message()):
        msg = await ch.get_json()
        print('Got Message:', msg)
        i = int(msg['sleep_for'])
        print('Sleep for {}'.format(i))
        await asyncio.sleep(i)
        print('End sleep')


async def main():
    sub = await aioredis.create_redis(('localhost', 6379))
    res = await sub.subscribe('chan:1')
    ch1 = res[0]
    tsk = await reader(ch1)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Also there is another test-app, which publishes json blobs with a `sleep_for` field which then used in a subscriber app to emulate some work inside a `reader` coroutine using a `sleep` statement.

I expected "sleeps" to run in "parallel" but in fact they appear in a sync manner on the screen, just one after the other.

My guess was that as soon as  hit the `await ch.get_json(..)` (or maybe even `await ch.wait_message()`) line I should be able to handle next message. On practice it runs like a synchronous code. Where am I wrong? This could be handled using connections pools, but this means that there is something not async and have no idea what exactly.

Comment: I am finding the question a bit hard to understand. If this is the only coroutine (which appears to be the case from your code example) then it will run repeatedly and sequentially within the while loop. i.e. it will wait for a message, sleep for a set duration, then repeat. In this case there won't be any effect of parallelism because it is a single coroutine. If you have multiple coroutines then asyncio will 'bounce' control back and forth when it encounters the `await` statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My guess was that as soon as hit the await ch.get_json(..) (or maybe even await ch.wait_message()) line I should be able to handle next message.

That's not how the `async/await` syntax works. Every time you hit a `await` in a coroutine, that coroutine will be "paused", giving control over to the called coroutine. It doesn't automatically process the next message if it's sleeping.

What you should do is use `ensure_future` to handle each message in a separate coroutine:

```
import asyncio
import aioredis

async def handle_msg(msg):
    print('Got Message:', msg)
    i = int(msg['sleep_for'])
    print('Sleep for {}'.format(i))
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    print('End sleep')

async def reader(ch):
    while (await ch.wait_message()):
        msg = await ch.get_json()
        asyncio.ensure_future(handle_msg(msg))

async def main():
    sub = await aioredis.create_redis(('localhost', 6379))
    res = await sub.subscribe('chan:1')
    ch1 = res[0]
    tsk = await reader(ch1)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Comment: Oh, yes. I do not why I thought that suspending the reader will allow to handler another client's reader call concurently. Thanks